# Adding a search bar to iPhone application that uses alphabetical sections?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an application that uses a UITableView which contains the names of products, these products are also split up into their respective sections based on their first letter.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        //Initialize alphabet array
        m_Alphabet = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K", @"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",@"Other", nil];

        //Initialize alphabet distionary of arrays
        m_AlphabetDictionary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //Populate distionary with a mutable array for each character
        //in the alphabet (plus one "Other" category)
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
            [m_AlphabetDictionary insertObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] atIndex: i];

        // The number of products in the database
        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //For each product in the appDelgates products
        for (Product *product in appDelegate.m_Products){
            if ([product.category isEqualToString:productType]){

                [tempArray addObject:product];

                //firstLetter is equal to the first letter of the products name
                NSString * l_FirstLetter = [product.name substringToIndex:1];
                //convert firstString to uppercase
                l_FirstLetter = [l_FirstLetter uppercaseString];

                //The added flag ensures objects whose first letter isn't a letter
                //are added to array 26
                bool added = NO;

                for(int i=0; i<[m_Alphabet count]; i++){
                    //If the first letter of product name is equal to the letter at index i in theAlphabet
                    if ([l_FirstLetter isEqualToString:[m_Alphabet objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                        //Add product to section array for that letter
                        [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:i] addObject:product];

                        added = YES;
                    }

                }
                //If product hasn't been added to array, add it to "Others" category
                if(!added)
                    [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:26] addObject:product];

            }
        }

    //Set navigation controller title
    self.title = productType;

}

//Number of sections is equal to the length of the m_Alphabet array
//Letters A-Z plus "Other"
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
        return [m_Alphabet count]; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
        return [[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:section] count]; 
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return m_Alphabet; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index 
{
    return [m_Alphabet indexOfObject:title]; 
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:section] count]==0) 
        return nil;

    return [m_Alphabet objectAtIndex:section]; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Cell for row");
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

    if([self.productType isEqualToString:@"All"]){
        Product *product = (Product *) [appDelegate.m_Products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = product.name;

        // Configure the cell.
        return cell;
    }
    else {

            //Instead of using appDelegate.products use the new array that will be filled
            //by the numberOfReowsInSection method
            Product *product = (Product *)[[m_AlphabetDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.textLabel.text = product.name;
            // Configure the cell.
            return cell;
    }
}
```

What I'm looking to do is add a search bar to the top of my table view that behaves just like the search bar in the "All Contacts" section in the iPhones contacts application.  I.E. When I search, all the sections disappear and just the search results are displayed until the search bar is blank again.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to uses  [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is most likely what the contacts application uses (along with mail, maps, safari, and music).  It presents itself as a table view overlay that may or may not contain a scope bar (your choice) and filters results based on the search bar's text.  A simple tutorial involving interface builder may be found [here](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/), and an apple example sans-IB may be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html).